# Pandas: Changing dataframe cell value via .loc raises a SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame called `mydf` below, from which I derived another DataFrame which is the tail end of `mydf`. I was experimenting to find out whether the `tail5` DataFrame below actually contains a *copy* or a *view* of the underlying `mydf` DataFrame. But when I update the value of a cell using the `.iloc` method, it raises the `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Any idea why? The Pandas [manual page on `tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) did not say anything about the nature of the data returned by the `tail` method (whether it returns a *view* [which can be modified with consequence of modifying the original data source] or a *copy* [which should not be modified for some reason]). Here's the code:

```
>>> mydf = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(10,3), columns=('a','b','c'))

>>> mydf
          a         b         c
0  0.263551  0.175394  0.570277
1  0.032766  0.243175  0.524796
2  0.034853  0.607542  0.568370
3  0.021440  0.685070  0.121700
4  0.253535  0.402529  0.264492
5  0.381109  0.964744  0.362228
6  0.860779  0.670297  0.035365
7  0.872243  0.960212  0.306681
8  0.698318  0.530086  0.469734
9  0.910518  0.697919  0.238539

>>> tail5 = mydf.tail(5)

>>> tail5
          a         b         c
5  0.381109  0.964744  0.362228
6  0.860779  0.670297  0.035365
7  0.872243  0.960212  0.306681
8  0.698318  0.530086  0.469734
9  0.910518  0.697919  0.238539

>>> tail5.loc[9,'a']= 0.8321
/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:189: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
/.../bin/ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

In my case above, the data in the underlying `mydf` was modified as a side effect of the `.iloc` assignment:

```
>>> mydf
          a         b         c
0  0.263551  0.175394  0.570277
1  0.032766  0.243175  0.524796
2  0.034853  0.607542  0.568370
3  0.021440  0.685070  0.121700
4  0.253535  0.402529  0.264492
5  0.381109  0.964744  0.362228
6  0.860779  0.670297  0.035365
7  0.872243  0.960212  0.306681
8  0.698318  0.530086  0.469734
9  0.832100  0.697919  0.238539
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the help function you can see that tail comes from the pandas.core.generic module:

[help(pandas.DataFrame.tail)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQDZK.png)

You then can see that the tail method returns the last 5 rows with iloc, meaning that it returns a subset of your dataframe. That is the reason why you have a warning message

[pandas.core.generic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2sO3.png)
By doing:

```
    mydf = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=('a','b','c'))
    tail5 = mydf.tail(5).copy()
    tail5.loc[9,'a']= 0.8321
```

The warning disappears